# Google Developer Console Statistics page

Tags: console

I just published my first app last night (YAY!), and I was checking out the Developer Console today and the counters for Downloads / Installs is still zero, which I kind of expected. I didnt think they would update it often anyways. The thing I havent seen is this "Statistics" page with trend charts and such other devs have talked about, where you can track other stats with graphs and such. Theres no link to it in my developer console so I feel like Im looking in the wrong place. Could someone help in finding it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to have at least 1 install before you can even have any statistics to see. As soon as you do, you will see a **Statistics** link under the # of installs.